# Database backup questions

Tags: sql-server

When we back up a database or log, what steps determine the name of the media set? Is it WITH MEDIANAME clause when we format the media? Is this information kept inside the header?
Or is this for naming a particular media (such as a particular tape)? Even though I don't see the point of naming the individual tape.

If I add a subsequent backup sets to the same media set, is it possible to change the media set name in anyway?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178062.aspx), a **media set** is an:

> [O]rdered collection of backup media, tapes or disk files, to which
>   one or more backup operations have written using a fixed type and
>   number of backup devices.

This comprises an ordered set of backup media, which can be tape, disk files, Azure Blob Storage, etc., but (and this is important) *not* a combination of two or more of these.

So if you create a media set, your backup media in that media set must be of the same kind.

On to your question about the name of the media set. According to the same article (emphasis added):

> Every volume of backup media (disk file or tape) contains a media
>   header that is created when [sic] **by the first backup operation** that uses
>   the tape (or disk). That header remains intact until the media is
>   reformatted.

The media set name is assigned by the `WITH MEDIANAME` keyword, as you surmise. It is not possible to change the name once you have created the first backup media in the set, because it is set by the first backup operation.

You will need to explicitly format the media set if you wish to change its name.

Comment: Thanks. So the media set name is saved in the header file and gone when header file is recreated ?

Comment: Yup. It's repeated in each backup media which forms part of that set.